# select blank value in database mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In my database there are 4 table and i want to join some entry from these table. If the entries of the 4 tables are all populated i can get result. But if one of the entry is not populated meaning on data in the database i dont get result. I tried changing the column that to null if they are empty still i get no result. I am using `INNER JOIN` for this and my query is like this. The problem i see here is when one of the column has null values i cannot select that table so my query is not firing. I need to have a complete entry for all the tables in order to fire the query to get result. Any idea is appreciated

```
SELECT *  FROM 
tbl1 t1 INNER JOIN 
tbl2 t2 ON 
t1.t1_id = t2.t1_id INNER JOIN 
tbl3 t3 ON 
t2.t3_id= t3.t3_id INNER JOIN 
tbl4 t4 ON t2.t4_id = t4.t4_id INNER JOIN 
tbl5 t5 ON t2.t5_id = t5.t5_id WHERE t5.t5_name LIKE ? AND t4.t4_name LIKE ? AND t3.t3_name LIKE ? AND t1.t1_name LIKE ?
```

`UPDATE`

Example if the t5_id in t2 is null then the query is not returning any result. If any ID (t1_id,t3_id,t4_id,t5_id) is null in t2 then it is not returning value. But if the id are complete then it is returning value

`t2 table` representation

```
t2_sysid      t1_id       t3_id       t4_id      t5_id
1             1           1           1          1
2             2           2                        
3             3           3           3          3
```

In this sample if i search for the entry two it will not be found because t4_id and t5_id is empty but 1 and 3 can be found because they are not empty

Comment: you could try `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER`

Comment: for all the inner join?

Comment: yep, all joins change to left outer and check results

Comment: same result when i choose to select the one with 2 column empty i dont get result if i select the complete one it shows the result i expect.

Comment: Have you tried using `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` ?

Comment: enlighten me i have not used it yet i have no idea how or where to use it if you are pertaining to database value my fields are not null so when they are not populated the value is automatically null right?

Comment: Use `OR`/`OR IS NULL` operator in `WHERE` clause and `LEFT JOIN` t3,t4,t5 to t2

Comment: it showed but some data are also included i mean some data that should not be there was include any other method that does not make me include `OR` values i want `AND` values so i get the precise data i want

Comment: So, you want rows where all values are 'like x' and at the same time you complain that something that is not 'like x' (because is null) is not showing up. If you allow only null as an alternative then write it this way: `(LIKE ? OR IS NULL) AND (LIKE ? OR IS NULL)...`

Comment: `(t4.t4_name LIKE ? OR IS NULL) AND ( t3.t3_name LIKE ? OR IS NULL)` returns an error sir error is `near 'LIKE '%%' OR IS NULL)`

Comment: That was pseudo code showing logic. Use full syntax `OR table.column IS NULL`